# Will MySQL performance degrade too much with 250k rows added per year?

Tags: mysql, database, performance

A table in my database is expected to grow about 250,000 rows every year.

My fear is that it may slow down the client app, and probably pass the 30 sec runtime of MYSQL.

What should I do about this? Would MySQL be able to handle this, or I should go for a stronger ( IMO ) database like Microsoft SQL 2012?

Comment: MySQL by itself should be fine. There are lots of companies using it to handle millions and millions of rows. But you need to answer how you're using it. Are you doing full table scans? Is your table properly indexed? I don't think your question is answerable in it's current form

Comment: This also depends on what hardware you'll have at your disposal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

250k rows is not huge. 10 million is still perfectly fine (40 years, I guess it won't last that long), even half the time (20 years) would still be a long time for a software system.

If you create your queries properly, and set the right indexes, you should be fine. Always check with `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` if your indexes are properly used on a query.

Comment: It all depends on the usage of the system, but I don't think a switch from MySQL to MSSQL will really be a big comparison either. With the right indexes, you should be just fine with MySQL or any other SQL solution.
http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/000796.html

Answer (score 1):

This heavily depends on your application and how it is calling the database.

Some general things to consider:

- Make proper use of `WHERE` clauses
- Make sure you have proper indexes in place

But a couple of million rows should not be an issue at all, if you get to the 100mio+ range you can start to think about this.